# Why does Windows use C:

Tags: windows

Right, first off, I'm from the '00s so although I never got to use `{MS,PC}-DOS`, I do know what they are, as well as being able to have used Windows 98 SE for a bit when I was younger.

So what I want to know is why does Windows use drive C: for the OS drive, more so, why does DOS do the same? Why not use something like `X:` (which I can say for a fact that the Windows 7+ install media does for the RAMDisk it creates)?

Comment: Possible, but not quite. I'm asking as to why the OS drive is positioned where it is, and not at a random place on the drive letter alphabet

Comment: system drive is C: because A: and B: was used for floppy disks, and that was answered in the other question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Way back when, most DOS computers had floppy drives. The first floppy drive was `A:` and the second floppy drive was `B:`. Because -- although floppies were absurdly small by today's standards -- some types of floppies were large enough that they couldn't be copied in a single pass through memory (copy original to memory, remove original, insert new, copy memory to new). To make copying a less tedious operation, it was very common to have two floppy drives, so `A:` and `B:` were reserved.

When hard drives started to become common, most machines still had at least one floppy, and a great deal of software assumed that both `A:` and `B:` were floppies. So, the first hard drive was assigned the name `C:` to avoid breaking the floppy custom.

Over the years that floppies remained common on machines that also had hard drives, the standard of `C:` as the first hard drive developed into a widely assumed rule, to the point that even after floppies became uncommon (and now obsolete), `C:` stuck as the assumed first hard drive.

Just to make things confusing, however, SSDs have started to replace hard drives as the `C:` drive -- and some software fails to respect that a lot of users prefer that really large installations to go on their hard drive (`D:`, for example) rather than their SSD.